# Etherjs v6 doesn't catch any events in the browser

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am working on simple smart contract interaction integration. And trying to make client's browser catch events.

Contract looks like

```
contract MyContract is Ownable {
    ....

    event Created(address _creator, unit256 _value);

    function create() public payable returns (uint256) {
        ....
        emit Created(msg.sender, msg.value);

    }
```

On the browser's side I am doing following:

```
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);

this.provider.on("block", (blockNumber) => {
  console.log("event Block: ", blockNumber);
});

this.provider.on("pending", (pendingTransaction) => {
  console.log("event Block: ", pendingTransaction);
});
```

and expecting to see something once Hardhat's network make new block (for instance - I calling contract's method from RemixIDE). But nothing.

Any idea what I should fix?

Using Ethers.js v6 as wrapper for ethereum provider.